# How to enter a user account and run commands from a shell script being run as root?

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, users, root

I am presently writing an automated install script for Arch Linux, to simplify the install process for myself (in case my current installation of Arch goes belly up and I can't fix it myself), but the problem is that I don't know how to enter a newly-created user account and execute a command in it from a shell script. I know that running `su - $USERNAME` will log me into the `$USERNAME` account. The problem is that after running this command all further lines in the shell script are ignored.

Comment: su - $USERNAME -c <command>

Comment: Also please consider of using sudo to run command as different user

Comment: Also, FWIW, there are tons of backup tools/strategies that are likely to work better then your script, why are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Firstly, because I have never used such tools, secondly because I would like others to be able to benefit from these scripts too. @LaurentiuRoescu your solution worked for me, if you want to write it up as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a command as another user:

```
su - $USERNAME -c <command>
```